# Difference between saving SharedPreferences in onPause() and onDestroy() methods

Tags: android

I am trying to save an int variable `int diff` and I am not sure where I should save it,in onPause() or in onDestroy() methods. This variable is used in an fragment, attached to the MainActivity statically.

The code is basic:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    SharedPreferences sp = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myPrefsName",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putInt("myPrefsInt",diff);
    editor.commit();
}
```

and for to retrieve it:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SharedPreferences sp = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myPrefsName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    diff = sp.getInt("myPrefsInt",1);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no guarantee that `onDestroy` will ever be called; once an activity has been moved to the background, it is fair game to be killed if system resources are required, even without calling `onDestroy`. Therefore, you should save in `onPause`, instead. Note that, for state associated with a specific instance of an activity, `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` may be more appropriate; however, `onResume` / `onPause` makes sense for global state like shared prefs.

Answer (score 2):

I recommended you to put it onPause() because if you want to used it on another activity the value will not be saved because the onDestroy() method will be called before exit the app but the onPause() method will be called when the other activity get started

Answer (score 2):

You should save it in onPause().

OnDestroy may not be called. See [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29)

Also from the docs:

> onPause() is typically used to commit unsaved changes to persistent data, stop animations and other things that may be consuming CPU, et

[source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you are using you variable for and when.

Saving the int onPause will pretty much guarantee it being saved as it is saved as soon as your activity gets hidden in any way. (User leaves app, a dialog is displayed etc.)

OnDestroy will only save your variable if you call finish() or android kills your activity.